# R dplyr filter space/special characters in column names

Tags: r, filter, dplyr, space

```
require(dplyr)
sampleDF <- data.frame("Column A" = c(1,2,3))
sampleDF %>%
  dplyr::filter(
    `Column A` > 2
  )
```

How should I fix the codes above so it works? I don't want to change the name.

Comment: I get column as `Column.A`, `sampleDF %>%
  filter(Column.A > 2)` works for me

Comment: What are you trying to fix? If you want the column to stay as `Column A` instead of `Column.A`, use `data.frame("Column A" = c(1,2,3), check.names = FALSE)`. Otherwise see comment from @RonakShah.

Comment: It is often useful to look a little more closely at your data when seeing behavior like this. Simpler things can be seen immediately with simpler meta-views like `colnames(sampleDF)`, and that alone might have shown that your column name was not as you thought. If you need to see some expectations of data within the columns, it helps to look at something like `str(sampleDF)`, which often identifies things like `character` vectors instead being `factor` or intended numbers actually being `character` or `factor`.

Comment: I'm quite used to data.table syntax (e.g. sampleDT[`Column A` > 2,]) so it's surprising to find dplyr doesn't deal with it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

dplyr is probably not the problem, because in general only dots and underscores are allowed in variable names, but no spaces. If you would like to include a quoted name under all circumstances, maybe:

```
require(dplyr)
require(rlang)
sampleDF <- data.frame("Column A" = c(1,2,3))
sampleDF %>%
  dplyr::filter(
    eval_tidy(quo("Column A")) > 2 # OR: eval(quote("Column A")) > 2
  )
```